# Good minimum size for single background image

Tags: css, image, background

I have a single image covering the entire background.  Do sites that do this usually choose an image size via JavaScript?  And if I didn't want to use JavaScript, what's a good minimum size to cover the vast majority of screens?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you going to justify your downvote?  Oh wait, you can't, my bad.  Looks like my dummy SO account going to take hit - ¡o nooes!

Comment: Upvoting because un-explained down voting pi55es me off!  Oh and I had exactly the same question too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to tell, an image that would fit nicely on a 10" netbook will not look the same on a 24" monitor, so your best bet is to use a jQuery plugin such as the [Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) or [Vegas](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) plugins or CSS3's `background-size:cover` property like so:

```
html {
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Granted, that will only work on modern browsers. [Here](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) are a few more techniques to achieve this goal.

Comment: Webkit-based browsers, Firefox and Opera understand background-size natively nowadays. You don't need to use vendor-prefixes anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The most used screen resolution is 1024x768 imo.
Also If I should use one background for a website, is should make the bottom fade out, or one color, or gradient.

Comment: That was last true around 2009. http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp

Comment: If anything, the screen sizes are diverging. You have more and more smart phones now, mini-laptops, gadgets like that. The one-size-fits-all approach is no longer feasible.